# 99% CPU usage of UICollectionView - Significant Location Change not calling "didUpdateLocations"

Tags: uicollectionview, uikit, profiling, core-location, cllocationmanager

What works is that the app gets launched into background on significant location change. In `AppDelegate` I check for the `UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocationKey` and init a location manager:

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters
locationManager.distanceFilter = 50
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

The initial view controller is a `UITabBarController` which shows a `UICollectionViewController`.

When I set that there are no cells in the UICollectionView everything works fine and `didUpdateLocations` of the `locationManager` gets called.

However when the `UICollectionView`'s `numberOfItemsInSection` returns 1, the `didUpdateLocations` does not get called. Instead the `UICollectionView` has 99% CPU usage for minutes until the app crashes.

I deleted all controls and all code from the cell, so it is an empty cell now, and still this happens.

In Time Profiler I see that is has something to do with `UICollectionViewData setLayoutAttributes`.

[image: Call stack in Time Profiler]

What's wrong here?

**Update 1:** There is the stack under `setLayoutAttributes`.

[image]

**Update 2:** The app works fine and never crashed when launched normally by the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Funny enough, the solution was to disable significant location changes once and running the app:

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = false
locationManager.stopMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

After reenabling it and running the app, it worked fine:

```
locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
locationManager.startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges()
```

I tried everything, from removing 3rd party frameworks to stripping down the app to a minimum of code and yes, I also did clean the build folder a 100 times.

Maybe something was wrong with the iOS register of apps to notify on significant location changes. Hope this saves someone the time it cost me to figure that out.

Answer (score 0):

You understand the code better than anybody on this site, *but* this looks suspicious:

[image]

You are running some kind of loop over Observers, whatever those are.
It looks like on each one it is doing a callback, and that is doing some kind of transaction that needs a commit, and as part of the commit it is displaying something, and as part of that it is doing a bunch of layout, of subviews and so on.
That's basically sopping up *all* of the time.

You might want to turn off the display updating until you're done.

Comment: Hi Mike, thanks for investigating, I did not call any observers, but I found the solution, see my answer above.